# Does "ask someone for something" mean to borrow?

Tags: word-usage

Does *ask someone for something* mean to borrow or it means to ask someone to give the person something permanently? For example:

> I asked my dad for a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be ambiguous at times.

Sometimes though, the wording can give a hint at the meaning

> I asked my dad for **a** phone.

In this sentence it looks like you've asked for your dad you provide/buy you a phone (for Christmas!?). If you wanted to be clear about that, you could have put '*a **new** phone*' to make it obvious it's not one your dad owns.

> I asked my dad for **his** phone.

In this sentence you have asked for something that belongs to someone else (and the ownership is stipulated in the sentence). Usually this implies borrowing - why would your dad give you his phone for keeps ? Of course if you added context, it could mean you wanted to own it '*... when he upgrades to a new one*'

> I asked my dad for a stapler

With a phone, a person would *usually* only have 1 and it would be intimately theirs. With a stapler, a person could have possession of several, and (usually) wouldn't be so attached to objects like this. This sentence then becomes a lot more ambiguous

Are you asking for him to buy/give you a stapler (one among his many staplers or maybe for Christmas!?) or are you just wanting to borrow one for a quick bit of craft?

Usually in these situations you would clarify, or expand to give context

> I asked my dad for a stapler *to do my homework* (borrow)
>   I asked my dad for a stapler *to take with me to college* (keep)
>   I asked my dad for a stapler *but he wouldn't lend it to me after last time* (borrow)
>   I asked my dad for a stapler *but he didn't have a spare one* (keep)

Although you could reword the sentence to include *borrow* or *have*:

> I asked my dad if I could [borrow/have] his stapler

Comment: Another issue is that you might *ask* to borrow something, but the person you ask either doesn't have the thing you want to borrow, or for some reason decides not to lend it to you.